# json array with same names

Tags: json, swift4

I am trying to parse through and record json data that has an array with multiple of the same title using swift4. I have included some of the raw json data below:

```
{
    "league": {
        "alias": "MLB",
        "name": "Major League Baseball",
        "id": "2fa448bc-fc17-4d3d-be03-e60e080fdc26",
        "date": "2018-07-07",
        "games": [
            {
            "game": {
                "id": "d9c6012e-4328-4283-9d6e-b95ff3d53106",
                "status": "scheduled",
                "coverage": "full",
                "game_number": 1,
                "day_night": "N",
                "scheduled": "2018-07-07T23:15:00+00:00",
                "home_team": "833a51a9-0d84-410f-bd77-da08c3e5e26e",
                "away_team": 
            },
            "game": {
                "id": "d9c6012e-4328-4283-9d6e-b95ff3d53106",
                "status": "scheduled",
                "coverage": "full",
                "game_number": 1,
                "day_night": "N",
                "scheduled": "2018-07-07T23:15:00+00:00",
                "home_team": "833a51a9-0d84-410f-bd77-da08c3e5e26e",
                "away_team": 
            }
       }
 ]
```

};

The following code are the structs to store the json data. I am getting an error on the leagueinfo line that says does not conform to decodable but I believe the issue is from the games struct. I cannot figure out how to bring in multiple items named "game":

```
struct League: Decodable{
    let league: LeagueInfo
    init(league: LeagueInfo ){
        self.league = league
    }
}

struct LeagueInfo: Decodable{
    let alias: String?
    let name: String?
    let id: String?
    let date: String?
    let games: Games?
}

struct Games{
    let game: [Game]

}

struct Game: Decodable{
    let id: String?
    let status: String?
    let coverage: String?
    let scheduled: String?
    let home_team: String?
    let away_team: String?
    let venue: [Venue]?
}
```

Any help would be greatly apreciated!

Comment: for struct Games, you have to set decodable

Comment: The JSON is nonsensical. For example a dictionary must have unique keys.

Answer (score 0):

I am looking at your "games" attribute. It seems your array is not json valid. I think your array is supposed to be like this.

```
json = {
    "games": [
        {
            "game": {
                "id": "d9c6012e-4328-4283-9d6e-b95ff3d53106",
                "status": "scheduled",
                "coverage": "full",
                "game_number": 1,
                "day_night": "N",
                "scheduled": "2018-07-07T23:15:00+00:00",
                "home_team": "833a51a9-0d84-410f-bd77-da08c3e5e26e",
                "away_team": ""
            }
        },
        {
            "game": {
                "id": "d9c6012e-4328-4283-9d6e-b95ff3d53106",
                "status": "scheduled",
                "coverage": "full",
                "game_number": 1,
                "day_night": "N",
                "scheduled": "2018-07-07T23:15:00+00:00",
                "home_team": "833a51a9-0d84-410f-bd77-da08c3e5e26e",
                "away_team": ""
            }
        }
    ]
};
```

Notice your extra curly brackets and missing commas.

Comment: yes, i was just grabbing a segment of the json but i will fix in OP